# Spring Batch - how to xml confgiure "Fault Tolerance"

Tags: spring-batch

how can I configure (xml-based) a Spring Batch Job that is "fault tolerant" ie. will honor the SkipPolicy on a **write** failure?

I found some documentation for JavaConfig but none for xml-based configuration.

So far it aborts the job on the first write failure.

Günni

Comment: use skip-limit or retry-limit (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html)

Comment: it turns out that spring was working as advertised, provided you configure the transaction manager properly. Folks that was a nightmare to figure out... Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch calls the skip policy when an item reader, processor, or writer throws an exception.
You can not define it on the writer level so I suggest you specify your own exception so it will be originated from the writer only;

You can use the default Spring batch policy withing the chunk element and use it with skip limit 
i.e.

```
<step id="stepWithSkipPolicy">
<tasklet>
    <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100" skip-limit="10"/>
        <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            <batch:include class="MyWriterException"/>
        </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

You can find additional skip policies under **org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip** package

You can plug your own policy using skip-policy attribute on the chunck level

```
<step id="stepWithSkipPolicy">
<tasklet>
    <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer" commit-interval="100"
           skip-policy="mySkipPolicy" />
    </tasklet>
</step>
```

The skip-limit attribute and the skippable-exception-classes
tag have no effect as soon as you plug your own skip policy into a step.